# Allow Catogories to a Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm creating a custom post type for a WP site and I want to allow categories for it. Sounds simple enough but for some reason when I go into the admin to create a new Case Study there is no way to add categories.

Here is the code to define the CPT. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
array(
            $labels = array(
                            'name' => 'Case Studies',
                            'singular_name' => 'Case Study',
                            'add_new' => 'Add Case Study',
                            'edit_item' => "Edit Case Study",
                            'view_item'  => "View Case Study" 
            ),
            $args = array(
                    'labels' => $labels,
                    'public' => true,
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'taxonomies' => array( "category" ),
                    'supports' => array(
                                            "title",
                                            "editor",
                                            "thumbnail",
                                            "custom-fields",
                                            "excerpt"

                                    )
            )


        );
register_post_type( 'Case Studies', $args );
```

Comment: The code is correct, but you have double quotes around category.

Comment: Doesn't matter. That is the first thing that I checked, even though I never had that issue before, and I am getting the same result.

Comment: Please show ALL the code then. From the start of registering to the end.

Comment: `register_post_type` should have case studies without spaces. (that's your post type key).

Comment: That is all of the code for registering that CPT.

Comment: You should have something like this:
`function Case_Studies()` at the beginning and `register_post_type( 'case_studies', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'Case_Studies', 0 );` at the end.

Comment: I've never done it that way and it has always worked fine. WP is registering this post type, as well as the 2 others I've created, just not attaching the categories to this one.

Comment: Well according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type the $post_type parameter can't contain spaces.

Comment: I'll be danged it worked! Thanks! Now I'm wondering why my code to set these up has never broken before... :-)